# Spring-boot form post large data taking long to enter filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have controller which would allow user to post data.

I'm sending 26,000 words large json in form using post method.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/post/?call=back" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="jsonInput" value='giantJSONSTRING'/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and my controller is simple

```
//Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
@Override
public ModelAndView loadPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView modelView) throws ApplicationException {
   String json = request.getParameter("jsonInput");

   return processRequestAndReturnModel(json);
}
```

It's taking 30s to reach my filter when I'm pointing to localhost.

anybody faced such issue?

Answer (score 1):

I saw similar problems, though with Apache HTTP Web server running on localhost. DNS resolution of `localhost` took some seconds. The resolution was to replace in the web server configuration to listen on `127.0.0.1`. Maybe you can try that, too, with embedded spring-boot application server, by setting in `application.properties`:

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
```

or

```
server.address=<your_local_ip>
```